# How can I save / get to Walmart's e-receipts from their Walmart app? Where are the files stored?

Tags: files

The Walmart app has a section called Savings Catcher, which allows one to scan a barcode from their receipt or to submit some numbers from it, and for the app to find lower prices. Anyhow, an exact digital duplicate of one's receipt is then shown. This receipt can be accessed at anytime (as far as I can tell). One can also zoom in on the receipt to view it at what looks to be 100% zoom.

**I really would like to be able to save these receipts in jpeg format. When one is looking at the receipt, there is no option for saving or sharing the receipt.**

Now, I am hoping that maybe the receipt gets saved somewhere on the phone or sd card, and am assuming that if it is, it might have an odd file extension (based on previous experience with another picture app. The file would open in photo programs and also if one would change the extension to .jpg.)

I have used ES File Explorer to search for anything named Walmart, but nothing shows up. I have no idea where the files are saved?

**Does anyone have any idea as to where the Walmart app's files are saved?**

My Android version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version this is supported on, but on mine, there is a share button at the top of the receipt, so you can share with email and the jpeg will be attached. Note, this is on the itemized view, not the receipt image view.

Comment: Currently the share function sends a png image.  I'm not sure why they aren't using pdf format since its mostly text.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be rooted to access it, but anything owned by an app will be in /data/data/[app package name] where [app package name] is the full package name for the app. Usually it will be something like com.walmart.mobile or similar.

Comment: The entire /data folder is empty. I am not sure if I connect it via USB to the computer if I will see things in it.

Comment: It's empty because your file manager isn't running as root